# Cross domain data pulling from database

Tags: json, ajax, cors, cross-domain

i have a website with some data in the database (phpmyadmin) on a domain www.domain1.com, and i need to use this data on a diffrent domain www.domain2.com. Is it possible?

I'm trying some ajax and json codes but with no success. I'm getting 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at **** (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Can someone help me with it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set out these headers in your **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

here **"*"** mean allow all origins if you only want to allow specific then add the domain of that website.
Rest of things would be make regular connection to database and good to go.

Comment: Thank you @Imran Ali. But how good is this for the security of the main website?

Comment: i have already mentioned if you use Asterisk it will allow http request from all sites so it's a good practice to use a domain name instead to whom you want to allow only.

Comment: In my case i can't specify a domain. I'm developing a wordpress plugin, where this plugin uses some data from the the main website.

Comment: then it's okay to use. there is no security issue.

Comment: Is there any news about how safe is this? I developing and API that in some case needs to connect to my database to write data. It can be from any website. So it safe to allow access from asteriks?